# Fabric Js - Is it possible to auto scale a image object to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

We currently upload an image via the below code:

```
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            fabric.Image.fromURL(event.target.result, function (img) {
                whiteboardService.uploadImageToCanvas(img);
            });
        }
```

and...

```
    service.uploadImageToCanvas = function (image) {
        service.canvas.add(image);

        image.id = service.getUniqueId();
        service.objectMap[image.id] = image;

        var data = {
            image: image,
            id: image.id
        };

        signalService.sendMessage(service.recipient, data);
    };
```

If the image is too large, bigger than our fixed width and height of the canvas would it be possible for that image to be scaled down automatically to fit into the fixed width and height of the canvas?

I should point out that I am using Angular.js as well

ta

Answer (score 23, accepted):

fabricjs put a very simple method to do this.
Those methods are `scaleToWidth` and `scaleToHeight` that are close to 'apply a scale factor that will fit the image on the specified dimensions'

So you can do

```
image.scaleToWidth(service.canvas.getWidth());
service.canvas.add(image);
```

it depends if you want to preserve aspect ratio if you have to scale for the biggest, the smallest or both.

Comment: I will need to preserve aspect ratio unfortunately, would it be possible to explain a little more about how I could do this?

Comment: This hasn't fixed a few other things that I am having problem with but has led me into the right direction so thank you for your help.

Comment: did it help you to scale the image to the size of canvas? it should have done it.

Comment: It did but I had to do a check after to find if the height was still  bigger than the canvas wqhich fixed all my problems

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @AndreaBogazzi, I wrote below code to fit image to canvas totally.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://d32ogoqmya1dw8.cloudfront.net/images/NAGTWorkshops/structure/SGT2012/activities/noaa_global_topographic_map.jpg', function(oImg) {
  let imgWidth = oImg.width;
  let imgHeight = oImg.height;
  let canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
  let canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

  let imgRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight;
  let canvasRatio = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
  if(imgRatio <= canvasRatio){
    if(imgHeight> canvasHeight){
      oImg.scaleToHeight(canvasHeight);
    }
  }else{
    if(imgWidth> canvasWidth){
      oImg.scaleToWidth(canvasWidth);
    }
  }

  canvas.clear();
  canvas.add(oImg);
  canvas.centerObject(oImg);
});
```

```css
.image-preview{
    border: solid 1px #979797;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-preview">
  <canvas id="canvas" width='200' height='200'></canvas>
  
  <hr/>
  <p>Origin Image</p>
  <img src="https://d32ogoqmya1dw8.cloudfront.net/images/NAGTWorkshops/structure/SGT2012/activities/noaa_global_topographic_map.jpg" />
</div>
```